# Does the iMac EFI Update 1.7 change how NetBooting works?

Tags: network, software-update, netboot, efi

I have a NetBoot server to manage all the Macs in my office. However, when I started a weekly backup of one of my iMacs last week, after rebooting and holding <kbd>N</kbd>, I saw the blinking globe for a few moments and then the system booted from the hard disk.

As far as I know, no configuration changes have been made to the NetBoot server. Other iMacs still can netboot fine.

This particular iMac had the [iMac EFI Update 1.7](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1470) installed whereas none of the other Macs have. I suspect that is the culprit especially given Apple's description:

> This update enables Lion Recovery from an Internet connection [...]

Does the iMac EFI Update 1.7 change how NetBooting works? If so, how specifically? Does the `vendor-class-identifier` of the DHCP request change?

(I'm happy to edit the question with additional details about my configuration if it will help)

---

**UPDATE:** I confirmed that the `vendor-class-identifier` in the DHCP request did *not* change after this update:

[image: DHCP Request]

And indeed, the server is sending back the proper booter filename and image path:

[image: DHCP Response]

So there's something else at play here...

Answer (score 1):

Yup they broke it. Early Internet recovery firmware versions don't netboot. later versions fixed this.